# How do i filter character that occurs more than 1 time using regex in Java?

Tags: java, regex, replace

I need a regex string that remove the duplicated characters that occurs more than 1 time.

for example :

```
eve -> e and v
eev -> e and v
```

i found one that like this : `(.)(?=\\1)`

that regex can remove duplicated characters that adjacent like : eev -> e and v

but that regex can not remove the second e after v in "eve" word.

Comment: So you want to remove repeats of a letter in a word, so eve and eev both become ev?

Comment: What would be the output of `eve`?

Comment: exactly, so even though the word is like this : evevvveeeve its still become e and v only

Comment: By e and v do you mean `ev`?

Comment: yes, the order doesn't matter

Comment: Then this is a duplicate. Check @MalteHartwig comment above.

Comment: sorry for the duplication, i've been searching for hours on so many site (including this site) but return to no avail. thank you for referencing that answer @revo. the answer is exactly what i want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 you can use :

```
String result = str.chars()
        .mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf((char) c))
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

**I/O**

```
eve         -> ev
eev         -> ev
evevvveeeve -> ev
```